# Clojurescript ajax post always returning nil value

Tags: ajax, clojure, clojurescript

I have an atom with vector of maps that describes my starting messages,like this...

```
 (def messages
(atom
[{:message "Hello world"
 :user    "Foo"}
{:message "Ajax is fun"
 :user    "Bar"}]))
```

I have my routes set up like this...

```
(defroutes home-routes

 (GET "/messages" [] (response/edn @messages))
 (POST "/add-message" [message user]

   (response/edn
     (swap! messages conj {:message message :user user}))))
```

In my clojurescript file i have this...

```
(defn render-message [{:keys [message user]}]
[:li [:p {:id user} message " - " user]])

(defn render-messages [messages]
(let [messages-div (domina/by-id "messages")]
(destroy-children! messages-div)
(->> messages
    (map render-message)
    (into [:ul])
    template/node
    (append! messages-div))))



(defn by-id [id]
(.getElementById js/document id))

(defn add-message []
(POST "/add-message"

   {:format :edn
    :params {:message (value (by-id "message"))
             :user    (value (by-id "user"))}
    :handler render-messages
    }))


(defn ^:export run [] 


(GET "/messages" {:handler render-messages})

(listen! (by-id "send")
      :click add-message)

)
```

And html...

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>

 <div id="messages"></div>
 <textarea id="message"></textarea>
 <br/>
 <input type="text" id="user"></input>
 <br/>
 <button id="send">add message</button>


<script type="text/javascript" src="hello.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  cfi_webservice.home.run();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Render message function is used to append new input into div,so my problem is when i click on the button with the send id new li is added into ul but with empty parameters...it is always nil.I am guessing that my add-message function is not alright because neither parameter is sent to /add-message route.Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Have you checked that your server code works, e.g. with `curl -X POST`?

Comment: yes it is working,GET is printing the messages from atom and post is also working...but i dont seem to get any parameters when i send them on click of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of :format :edn i used :format :raw and it is working now.

Comment: This answer DOES help!